# How to parse Json WebApi response containing C# list

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api, json.net

hi I have a json response like

> {"Status":"Success","Message":"Authentication
>   successful","Data":{"Key":"sdsdIRs99Iebe6QHmawlBsCks9mqfUt6jKYNQ%2bW","UserId":"ddjjj8-11e6-637af7"}}

how can I parse this to read response.

I am doing this way:

```
private void POST(string url) 
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";

    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

    postData="{\"UserName\": \"abc\"," +"\"Password\": \"mypwd\"}";

    Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    request.ContentType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }

    long length = 0;

    try 
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response =  (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            length = response.ContentLength;
             using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
             {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();

                string str= objText;
                MyObject myojb = (MyObject)js.Deserialize(objText,typeof(MyObject));           
            }
        }                       
    }
    catch (WebException ex) 
    {
        // Log exception and throw as for GET example above
    }
}
```

I am able to read "Status" and "Message" but unable to read "Key" and "UserID" values.

Please help!

Comment: ASP.NET Web API itself uses Json.NET. JavaScriptSerializer is obsolete and a lot slower. It shouldn't be used in client code at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Newtonsoft Json` instead of `JavaScriptSerializer` the class structure for your json looks like this

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization could be done easily like

```
Rootobject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);

Console.WriteLine(ro.Status + ", " + ro.Message + ", " + ro.Data.Key + ", " + ro.Data.UserId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Guessing (since we don't know the structure of the MyObject class) how you access your data:

```
String status = myobj.status;
String message = myobj.message;
```

Now since the other data properties are in the "data" node of your json, you should be able to access them like this:

```
String key = myobj.data.key;
String userId = myobj.data.userId;
```